# Following Page Object Model how should I structure classes if I have multiple websites?

Tags: java, oop, selenium-webdriver, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

For a selenium POM project, I am using two different websites. Each website have pages with common functionality and variables, for example splash screens, headers, etc, but the values themselves are different. I currently have a BasePage with common objects, like PageActions (which has all of the clicking and entering text functionality etc) and URL. All pages extend BasePage.

I want to now further refactor the classes, one way I thought of would be to have a Base Page for website 1 that extends BasePage and another Base Page for website 2 that also extends BasePage. Then, pages of website 1 would extend Base Page for website 1.
Is there a better way to organise this, maybe using abstract classes?